# Subject relative clause

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

About subject relative clauses, look at this example:

Nina is an interesting woman who/that sits across from me (1). (Touchstone 3)

My Q here is: by using this defining relative clause am I talking about the subject complement or subject or there isn't any difference?

For example, would be alright if I told: Nina, who sits across from me, is an interesting woman (2)?

Do these two have the exact same grammatical structure or they are different? Isn't my second example a non-defining relative clause then? Do I need to put commas in the second example?

Comment: The relative clause is modifying "interesting woman", which is subjective PC referring to "Nina".

Comment: Assuming that there is only one Nina, your second example is of a non-defining relative clause that requires commas.